# Image of multiplication map in tensor powers of finite-dimensional ring

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $R$ be a (commutative, unital) ring of dimension $n$ over a field $k$. Assume the characteristic of $k$ is greater than $n$.

Then $R^{\otimes n}$ has a natural ring structure, together with an $S_n$-action. It also can be viewed as the usual tensor product, in particular, containing the one-dimensional subspace $\wedge^n R$.

For which rings is the image of the multiplication map $R^{\otimes n} \otimes \wedge^n R \to R^{ \otimes n}$ isomorphic, as a representation of $S_n$, to the regular representation?

It is not too hard to see that this property is preserved by products of rings, so we may reduce to the local case.

This property is satisfied for the rings $k[x]/x^n$:

---

Indeed, we're looking at the image of the multiplication by $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{ \sigma(i)-1}$ map in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/ (x_1^n,\dots, x_n^n)$. The kernel of this multiplication map includes the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1,\dots, e_n$ in $x_1,\dots, x_n$, so we can view it as a map $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(e_1,\dots, e_n) \to k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/ (x_1^n,\dots, x_n^n)$.

The ring $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(e_1,\dots, e_n)$ is isomorphic to the regular representation as an $S_n$ module because it is the fiber over $0$ of the map $(x_1,\dots, x_n)\mapsto (e_1,\dots, e_n)$ from $\mathbb A^n$ to $\mathbb A^n$, which is a finite map between smooth varieties, hence flat, so the representation of $S_n$ on each fiber is independent of the fiber, and is therefore the regular representation since it's the regular representation on the generic fiber.

So it suffices to show that this map is injective. (Note that the map twists the $S_n$-action by the sign character, but this preserves the regular representation.) Since the map is $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$-linear, the kernel is a submodule, and because $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(e_1,\dots, e_n)$ is Gorenstein, it suffices to check the kernel doesn't contain the unique minimal submodule, which is generated by $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{i-1}$, whose product with $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{ \sigma(i)-1}$ is congruent modulo $x_1^n,\dots, x_n^n$ to $\pm \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{n-1} \neq 0$

---

A necessary condition for this property is that $R$ be Gorenstein.

---

Indeed, if the image is isomorphic to the regular representation then it must contain an $S_n$-invariant vector. Since we multiply by a vector on which $S_n$ acts by the sign representation, this only happens if we multiply another vector on which $S_n$ acts by the sign representation, i.e. it's necessary for the multiplication map $\wedge^n R \otimes \wedge^n R \to R^{\otimes n}$ to be nonzero.

Assume $R$ is not Gorenstein. We may assume $R$ is local. Let $r_1,\dots, r_n$ be a basis of $R$ with $r_1=1$, $r_1,\dots, r_n$ in the maximal ideal, and $r_{n-1}, r_n$ two linearly independent vectors which are both zero divisors with the maximal ideal (which necessarily exist since $R$ is not Gorenstein). Then $\wedge^n R$ is generated by $\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) r_{\sigma(1)} \otimes r_{\sigma(2)} \otimes r_{\sigma(n)}$.

Thus $\wedge^n R \otimes \wedge^n R$ is generated by the product of two such generators, i.e. a sum over pairs of permutations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$. If $\sigma_1(i)=n$ or $\sigma_2(i) = n-1$, then the term corresponding to $(\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$ can only be nonzero if the product $r_{\sigma_1(i)} r_{\sigma_2(i)}$ is nonzero, which happens only if $\sigma_2(i)=1$. This can't happen for both of the two different values of $i$ that satisfy $\sigma_1(i)=n$ or $\sigma_2(i) = n-1$, so each term is zero, and hence the product is zero, as desired.

---

I think I checked that this was true for the ring $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$ but I'm not very confident in that.

This question was motivated by a perhaps-quixotic attempt to understand in a more algebraic vector the tensor vector bundles defined by Jenia Tevelev and Sebastián Torres in their paper [The BGMN conjecture via stable pairs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.11951).

Comment: This reminds me of Haiman's work on the isospectral Hilbert scheme. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010246 Haiman builds a flat, rank $n!$ cover of $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{A}^2)$ whose fiber over the points of $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{A}^2)$ corresponding to reduced quotients of $k[x,y]$  is, I am pretty sure, the same $n!$ dimensional thing you construct. But I am puzzled because Haiman's construction works at the points of $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{A}^2)$ corresponding to non-Gorenstein quotients of $k[x,y]$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Couldn't they agree at some points and disagree on others?

Comment: Yes, they could, it is a feeling of oddness, not a contradiction. Actually, Haiman's scheme is the reduced fiber product of $\text{Hilb}^n(\mathbb{A}^2)$ and $\mathbb{A}^{2n}$ over $\text{Sym}^n(\mathbb{A}^2)$. I wonder whether your thing could be the naive fiber product, without taking the reduction?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer That would be "too big" whereas my thing in the non-Gorenstein case is too small. Note that the rank of the fiber product construction can only jump under specialization, while the rank of the image of a linear map can only shrink under specialization. But the Haiman work is really interesting - it might, for example, be a better approach to what I was trying to do than my approach!

Comment: There are a lot of details to check, which is why I am not leaving an answer yet, but I think Haiman is looking at the $R^{\otimes n}$ submodule of $\omega_R^{\otimes n}$ generated by $\bigwedge^n \omega_R$. (Concretely, the dualizing module $\omega_R$ is just $\mathrm{Hom}(R,k)$ with $R$-module structure induced by the $R$-module structure on $R$.) This would be the same thing for $R$ Gorenstein, but maybe better in general?

Comment: For example, take $R = k[x,y]/\langle x,y \rangle^2$. Then $\omega_R$ can be thought of as the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq 1$ in $k[u,v]$, with $x$ acting by $\partial/\partial u$ and $y$ acting by $\partial/\partial v$. Then $\omega_R^{\otimes 3}$ is the same thing in variables $(u_1, v_1, u_2, v_2, u_3, v_3)$. The subspace $\bigwedge^3 \omega_R$ is spanned by $\det \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ 1&1&1 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, so you are looking at the vector space spanned by all derivatives of this determinant. Now Haiman's "$n!$-Theorem" says you win.

Comment: Tesler ( https://doi.org/10.1006/jcta.1998.2913 , Section 8) computed that, if you do the same thing with $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\langle x_1,\ldots, x_n \rangle^2$, you get a space of dimension $\binom{2n}{n}$, which is equal to $(n+1)!$ for $n=1$ and $2$, but not for larger $n$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Thanks! So it seems my statement is likely true for Gorenstein rings of embedding dimension $2$ (which is a little different from the condition I wildly guessed, which is lci) and the modified statement is true for rings of embedding dimension $2$. I wonder if it is false for literally all rings of higher dimension or just some....